# xsl stylesheet works on server in IE and Firefox, works locally only with IE

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser, xslt-1.0

I have an xml document and associated xsl stylesheet.

When I put the xsl and xml up on my server the xsl styleheet is applied and the XML document renders correctly in IE, Firefox and Chrome.  When I pull the files down locally (into the identical file structure), the document renders correctly in IE but not in Firefox or Chrome.  In Firefox, I don't get an error msg but it just displays one long stream of text, as if it's passing the XML document content straight through without applying any of the xsl. In Chrome, I also don't get any kind of error msg, but the screen is blank, nothing at all, but again no error.

Stats: 
Firefox 20.0.1
IE 9
Chrome Version 26.0.1410.64 m

XSL file begins like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
```

XML file begins like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="../styles/newberry.xsl"?>

<!DOCTYPE ead PUBLIC "+//ISBN 1-931666-00-8//DTD ead.dtd (Encoded Archival Description (EAD) Version 2002)//EN" "http://library.syr.edu/digital/guides/lavender/ead.dtd">
<ead>
[blah blah rest of document]
</ead>
```

FWIW, I did try changing the stylesheet path from a relative one to an absolute one on the local version of the xml file and it didn't help.  I'm not sure where to go from here.  Suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 1):

It's a security feature. For local files, Firefox (and presumably Chrome, too) won't load a stylesheet that isn't in the same directory as the XML file. You can find more information in this [Firefox bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=397894).

Comment: OK, this fixes Firefox.  However, this does not appear to fix the problem in chrome.  I still get the blank white page in Chrome.

Comment: @user2280071 For Chrome, see the question [Can Chrome be made to perform an XSL transform on a local file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828898/can-chrome-be-made-to-perform-an-xsl-transform-on-a-local-file)