# "Protocols, domains, and ports must match" problems

Tags: javascript, facebook, adsense

My website have these error messages when i view it on console.
Can anybody tell me what is the problems that usually caused these error messages?

> Blocked a frame with origin "mysite" from accessing a frame with
>   origin "facebook". The frame being accessed set "document.domain" to
>   "facebook", but the frame requesting access did not. Both must set
>   "document.domain" to the same value to allow access.
>   contentscript_siteoverlay_bin.js:78
>
> Blocked a frame with origin "mysite" from accessing a frame with
>   origin "youtube". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
>   contentscript_siteoverlay_bin.js:78
>
> Blocked a frame with origin "mysite" from accessing a frame with
>   origin "googleads". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
>   contentscript_siteoverlay_bin.js:78
>
> Blocked a frame with origin "mysite" from accessing a frame with origin
>   "facebook".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the
>   frame being accessed has a protocol of "https". Protocols must match.

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 8):

iframes and the main page have to match protocols  ( `Http://` and `Https://` )

a secure site can not communicate with a not-secure site

just make everything secure to make things easier.  Sites like Facebook are going to require it anyways.

Comment: @Trip they cannot be if you get that message.

Comment: @Trip I had the same problem. This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828898/can-chrome-be-made-to-perform-an-xsl-transform-on-a-local-file#answer-3839054

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access values in the embedded facebook page. That is against the Same Domain Policy. The two sites can communicate using postMessage if you control both sites, but I doubt that you control the facebook part ...

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide some information about the browser where you're getting those errors?

Because **Chrome** have a know error related with your issue.
More info [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=17325).