# Javascript Undefined Function Errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, function, undefined

Click for my [subject site](http://www.guytgunterappliances.com/videos/)

I'm getting these errors on the video page on my site. They are preventing my videos from loading and changing to one another. I have very little experience with javascript so I would appreciate any help.

```
jquery.coda-slider-2.0.js:12TypeError: ‘undefined’ is not a function (evaluating ‘$’)
 menu.js:12TypeError: ‘undefined’ is not a function (evaluating ‘$(document)’)
 videos:365TypeError: ‘undefined’ is not a function (evaluating ’$(function(){

// Accordion
$(“.accordion”).accordion({
header: “.AccordionHeader”,
autoHeight: false
});
})‘)
videos:379TypeError: ’undefined’ is not a function (evaluating ’$(function() {
$( “.tabs” ).tabs();
})‘)
videos:393TypeError: ’undefined’ is not a function (evaluating ’$(function() {
$( “.dialog” ).dialog();
})’)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807200/jquery-uncaught-typeerror-property-of-object-object-window-is-not-a-funct

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16879538/protocols-domains-and-ports-must-match-problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are using [$.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/), but the `jquery.coda-slider` library is not designed to work in a non-conflict environment.

Also it looks like in the page itself there are multiple places where `$` is used without passing jQuery to it.

Solution 1: If there is no reason to use `noConflict()` remove it

Solution 2: Update the code and libraries to use jQuery in a non-conflict environment

Answer (score 0):

You just need to include your Jquery library before your plugin jquery.coda-slider-2.0.js

Try removing this line or move after all plugins loaded `try{jQuery.noConflict();}catch(e){};`