# how to link xsl stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt

Am I missing something? Do I need a server to execute this based on [this demo](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_transformation.asp)

I have the two files cdcatalog.xml and cdcatalog.xml

by adding the second line:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
   <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cdcatalog.xsl"?
    <!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
    <catalog>
        <cd>
            <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
            <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
            <country>USA</country>
            <company>Columbia</company>
            <price>10.90</price>
            <year>1985</year>
        </cd>
        <cd>
```

to the xml file, it should work. I'm trying it off my desktop just for kicks -is this not working because it needs to run off a server?

Comment: Are you attempting to load the XML in Chrome? If so, you will either need to enable a switch to allow file access http://stackoverflow.com/a/15999947/14419, or host on a local webserver and access via HTTP. Or try loading with another browser, such as Firefox or IE.

Comment: The processing instruction in the example that you posted is not correct. It is missing the closing `>`. Verify that the second line in your file is: `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cdcatalog.xsl"?>`. Firefox will render an XML parsing error about an unclosed token.