# Testing xslt code using your browser

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Using my browser, I want to test if my xslt code is working.

Currently I am copy pasting my xml and xslt code into [w3school's example page](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog) and test it there.

However, this is a real pain, since inserting tabs don't work there, syntax highlighting isn't active and the output window is too small. It is inconvenient to test your code there in general.

So:

- What do I have to setup to test my xslt code?
- Do I have to change the name of the xslt file to xhtml or html?
- How do you test xslt code in general?

I want to call the link `file://code.xslt` in my browser and see the result, for example.

I am on Ubuntu, Linux.

---

#### Testing with Chrome

To circumvent chrome's same origin policy, I had to restart chrome with `google-chrome --allow-file-access-from-files`.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15999947/3739455) and [here](http://www.chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/) is more info.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet but you can use Xml Notepad by Microsoft to test Xslt Documents, if you are working on a windows machine.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Sadly, I am on Ubuntu (Linux). Updated my answer to avoid any confusion :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A super-simple way to test your XSLT in a browser is to add the following header to your XML source document:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="mystylesheet.xsl"?>
```

then load it (the XML source) in the browser.

Another option is to use a stand-alone HTML document with some javascript to load your XML and XSLT documents and initiate the transform.

None of these can really replace a dedicated application. Note also that you have tagged this with XSLT 2.0, but I don't know of any browser that supports it.