# How to document a metro based JAX-WS application

Tags: web-services, jax-ws, java-metro-framework, enunciate

I've developed some JAX-WS web services using the Metro implementation.

Now what I want to add to these web services is somehow documentation. Metro, itself, generates you a "simple" doc html file, which includes the location of the WSDL and something more.

So I've been doing some research and I've found Enunciate, which helps you to generate documentation and your web services' client(s) in several programming languages (which is reeaaally helpful). But I'm only interested in the generation of documentation, for the time being. I can see that supports Apache CXF, JAX-WS, JAX-RS but doesn't support Metro, or I haven't been able to find the plugin.

So, will I be able to generate documentation for my web services?

Is there any other tool to generate documentation of a JAX-WS application (metro based)?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Just noticed this interesting question. What do you mean by "simple doc html file" that Metro generates?
There is a neat tool that generates documentation from WSDL and we have been using it for years, I'll explain it in a separate answer if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: @MiljenMikic metro generates a simple html documentation page on the root, where appear service name, service port, wsdl location, location and implementation class. By the way, I did found a tool which helps you documentate lots of applications: http://enunciate.webcohesion.com/

Answer (score 1):

Enunciate that you have found is indeed powerful, goes beyond than just documenting the service. However, if you are just searching for a documentation, there is a neat tool that our team is using for quite some time - Tomi Vanek's [WSDL viewer](http://tomi.vanek.sk/index.php?page=wsdl-viewer).

It is very simple to use, just attach already provided .xsl file in addition to the existing .wsdl file, enhance .wsdl file with a line

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="wsdl-viewer.xsl"?>
```

and then open .wsdl file in browser. You will see something like this: (just prepared a demo :))

[image]

Some remarks:

- adding documentation to .wsdl file is performed with `<wsdl:documentation>` tags
- you will be able to open such .wsdl file in all modern browsers except Chrome, due to the fact that [Chrome blocks XSL transform on a local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828898/can-chrome-be-made-to-perform-an-xsl-transform-on-a-local-file)

HTH.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's good to know the existence of a tool like yours :)

Comment: @russellhoff You are welcome! However, I don't take credit for this tool, Tomi Vanek is the author, we've just been using it so I thought it would be nice to share.