# xml xslt not displaying in ie or chrome but dipsplaying in firefox just fine

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to format an xml file using xslt and css. When I open it in IE it displays the text within  my  tag. Chrome displays nothing, and firefox displays it correctly how I styled it.

Here is a clip of the xml I wish to style.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="devices.xsl" ?>
<mpreader>
    <heading>Example</heading>
    <firmware>Firmware.134</firmware>
    <sn>123455</sn>
    <devices>
        <device id="01">
            <category>sim</category>
            <description>sim</description>
            <readable>yes</readable>
            <code size="00 18" crc="053F">test</code>
            <atr>4566</atr>
```

Here is my xsl file.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">h1{color:red;}</style>
    </head>
    <body style="text-align:left;">
        <h1>
            <xsl:value-of select="mpreader/heading"/>
        </h1>
        <h1>
            <xsl:value-of select="mpreader/firmware"/>
        </h1>
        <h1>
            <xsl:value-of select="mpreader/sn"/>
        </h1>
        <h1>
        </h1>
        <div>
            <xsl:value-of select="mpreader/devices/device/category"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="mpreader/devices/device/description"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="mpreader/devices/device/readable"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="mpreader/devices/device/code"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="mpreader/devices/device/atr"/>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue directly related to Chrome security policy.

[Can Chrome be made to perform an XSL transform on a local file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828898/can-chrome-be-made-to-perform-an-xsl-transform-on-a-local-file)

Comment: it is version 11 @ahkar5

Comment: Ok im not quite sure how but it seems to have fixed itself. It now displays just fine in internet explorer as well as firefox. Thank you for the information on chrome.