# xslt convert xml to html

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have 2 files, xml and xsl. I want to use xslt to take the xml data and convert to html table. Code below is not working in Chrome and I'm not sure why, any advice on how to use xslt properly AND/OR alternatives to xslt?

**test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="style.xsl"?>
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Greatest Hits</title>
        <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>RCA</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1982</year>
    </cd>
</catalog>`
```

**style.xsl**

```
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Artist</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="title" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="artist" /></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
   </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing, your XSLT is missing the opening tag for the `xsl:template` instruction:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
```

For another, there is an inherent problem with running XSLT locally in Chrome - see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3839054/3016153 (and others).

Comment: Bummer...any recommendations on how to accomplish same work without using XSLT?

Comment: I don't think you'll find a comparable tool. Try serving the stylesheet - or perhaps setup your browser as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18586921/3016153

Answer (score 1):

You can use XSLT on the server side and serve HTML content directly, this way you won't have to worry about browser.

I already did it in java, but I am pretty sure you have XSLT engine in other languages too.