# Browsers don't parse stylesheet properly

Tags: html, xml, parsing, xslt

I have an XML File:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet hred="remakes.xsl" type="text/xsl" ?>
<remakes>
<remake>
<rtitle>Pygmalion</rtitle>
<ryear>1938</ryear>
<fraction>0.5</fraction>
<stitle>Pygmalion</stitle>
<syear>1937</syear>
</remake>...
```

and I have created a stylesheet:

```
 ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/remakes">
<html>
<body>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>rtitle<</th>
        <th>fraction<</th>
        <th>stitle<</th>
        <th>syear<</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="remake">
        <xsl:value-of select="rtitle"/></td>
        <xsl:value-of select="fraction"/></td>
        <xsl:value-of select="stitle"/></td>
        <xsl:value-of select="syear"/></td>
    </xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But browsers don't parse it so instead of a table there is chaos. Is there a mistake in the code?

Comment: Missing the < in the very first line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your stylesheet, although they could always be typos with your question, but as there are too many to mention in comments, they are as follows:

1. The namespace prefix `xsl` has not been bound. You should type `xmlns:xsl="..."`
2. There is a `<` symbol in each table header `<th>rtitle<</th>`. If you really wanted this, you should write it as `<th>rtitle&lt;</th>`, but more likely it should just be `<th>rtitle</th>`
3. You have a closing `<\td>` for each row, but no opening `<td>` tag.
4. You also really need to wrap those `<td>` in a `<tr>` tag for it to be rendered properly.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/remakes">
<html>
<body>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>rtitle</th>
        <th>fraction</th>
        <th>stitle</th>
        <th>syear</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="remake">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="rtitle"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="fraction"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="stitle"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="syear"/></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Also `hred` needs to be `href` in the XML.

Comment: thank you, I didn't notice my stupid spelling mistakes :)it works in Firefox, but not in Chrome:(

Comment: If you running the XML / XSLT locally from your file system (rather than from a web server), then Chrome disallows this. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828898/can-chrome-be-made-to-perform-an-xsl-transform-on-a-local-file