# Run a xml/xsl in chrome (ERROR Unsafe attempt to load URL.....)

Tags: xml, google-chrome, xslt

I tryied to run an xml/xsl in chrome (it works on firefox) but I have this error :

Unsafe attempt to load URL file:///C:/Users/..../thing.xsl from frame with URL file:///C:/Users/..../thing.xml. 'file:' URLs are treated as unique security origins.

How can I fix it ? I found few solutions on internet but nothing works (--allow-file-access-from-files don't work).

Comment: Same problem here, except the xsl URL is on a remote site (http://foo.com/thing.xsl) in my case.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828898/can-chrome-be-made-to-perform-an-xsl-transform-on-a-local-file

Answer (score 3):

To anyone having this problem, if you use visual studio code, you can download the extension Live Server, run the server and then you can work with the files.