# Can Safari be made to perform an XSL transform on a local file?

Tags: xml, xslt, safari

Basically the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3828898/4959628), but for Safari.

When I try to open an XML file (`test.xml`) on my local filesystem that references an XSL file (`test.xsl`) in the same directory, Safari doesn't render anything and instead only gives this error in the web dev console:

```
Unsafe attempt to load URL file:///Users/john/test.xsl from frame
with URL file:///Users/john/test.xml. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

Is there a way to tell Safari to treat local files from the same directory as same-origin?

*Edit*: I just didn't look hard enough. "Developer->Disable Local File Restrictions" does what I need, even though that seems to disable all local file restrictions, whereas I only want to be able to include files from subdirectories.

Comment: If that answers your own question, post it as an answer and not an edit to the question.

Comment: Thought you'd have to wait two days to *answer* your own questions; apparently, you only have to wait to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can disable *all* local file restrictions in Safari by checking `Developer->Disable Local File Restrictions`.